# Как в перечисление добавить значение

Tags: java

Например есть перечисление

```java
enum week{
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY
}
```

как сделать так, чтобы при вызове `SUNDAY` появлялось значение 7, `MONDAY 1` и т.д.

```java
System,out.println(SUNDAY) // вывод 7
```

Comment: если у вас в енаме не 3 дня недели, а , как обычно , 7 и они номеруются с понедельника по воскресенье, то никаких доп.переменных заводить не надо.     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.ordinal()+1);
    }

Comment: Ruslan, проголосуйте и примите ответ, что вам помог :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действия:

- В `enum` добавляете поле для хранения значения и конструктор.
- Указывая значения перечисления указываете номер дня
- Чтобы видеть значение перечисления без обращения к полю `value`, нужно переопределить метод `toString`

Пример:

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
   MONDAY(1),
   TUESDAY(2),
   WEDNESDAY(3),
   THURSDAY(4),
   FRIDAY(5),
   SATURDAY(6),
   SUNDAY(7);
   
   int value;
   DayOfWeek(int value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
   
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "" + value;
   }
}
```

Тест:

```
System.out.println("SUNDAY: " + DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.value);
System.out.println("MONDAY: " + DayOfWeek.MONDAY.value);

System.out.println("SUNDAY.toString(): " + DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
```

Результат:

```
SUNDAY: 7
MONDAY: 1
SUNDAY.toString(): 7
```

Comment: Получается выводятся в стринге не интеджер? А как чтобы интеджер?

Comment: @Ruslan, да, там строка. Через `enum` никак, `DayOfWeek.SUNDAY` и прочие являются объектами самого `DayOfWeek`. Как писал в ответе вы можете у них вызывать поле `value`

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
enum week {
    SUNDAY(7), MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2);

    private int value;

    week(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return Integer.toString(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Получается выводятся в стринге не интеджер? А как чтобы интеджер?

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? `System.out` это поток вывода типа PrintStream. Он в методах print/println принимает объекты разных типов и выводит их в _текстовом виде_ в стандартный поток вывода. Где и что вы хотите получить в виде int?